# Width issue with website dropdown menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, drop-down-menu

So ive just started the master page for my new site and i put in a dropdown menu which i tested out by dropping it from the home button. Image below:

http://prntscr.com/28qnk2

My problem occurs when i tried to apply the same code to my plugins button in the menu, the whole thing spaces out. Image below:

http://prntscr.com/28qpky

This is the first time ive tried to build in a dropdown menu so my initial attempts probably have some issues with them but i cant seem to get this to work. Here is the code for the menu (html).

```
<div id="menu">
                    <table id="menu_table">
                    <tr>

                    <td id="home" class="menu_item" style="position:relative; z-index: 1000">
                        <ul class="dropdown">
                            <li><p>Home</p>
                                <ul>
                                    <li>One</li>
                                    <li>Two</li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </td>

                    <td id="about_us" class="menu_item">About Us</td>

                    <td id="plugins" class="menu_item">
                        <ul class="dropdown">
                            <li><p>Plugins</p>
                                <ul>
                                    <li>One</li>
                                    <li>Two</li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </td>

                    <td id="tutorials" class="menu_item">Tutorials and Help</td>

                    <td id="staff" class="menu_item">Staff</td>

                    <td id="chat" class="menu_item">ChatRoom</td>

                    </tr>
                    </table>
                </div>
```

and here is the CSS for the menu:

```
#menu   {
    position:relative;
    float:right;
    margin:2px;
    margin-right:13%;
    width:52%;
    height:77px;
    }
#menu_table{
    position:relative;
    top:12%;
    height:76%;
    width:100%;
    border-spacing:0px;
    }
.menu_item:first-child{
    border-left:1px solid #40d7bc;
    }
.menu_item:hover{
    background-color: black;
    color:#40d7bc;
    }
.menu_item{
    border-right:1px solid #40d7bc;
    text-align:center;
    }
ul.dropdown li ul { 
    display:none;
    position:absolute;
    z-index:100;
    padding-left:50%;
    top:35px;
    width:100%;
    }
ul.dropdown li ul li {
    position:relative;
    border-top:30px solid black;
    left:-50%;
    background-color: black;
    }
ul.dropdown li ul li:last-child {
    border-bottom:15px solid black;
    }
.menu_item li {
    list-style-type: none;
    }
```

and finally the small bit of jQuery i used.

```
function() { 
    $('ul', this).stop(true, true).slideToggle(100); },
function() { 
    $('ul', this).stop(true, true).slideToggle(100); }
);
```

Thanks for any help on this, im completely lost on whats wrong with it.

The only idea i may have with what the issue is, is how i aligned the text to the center. I did it by padding the ul containing the submenus by 50% width, this way the left side of the ul was down the middle and when i shifted the submenu items left by 50% width they were in the middle. You're probably thinking why shift them at all, well for some reason if i left them in the middle it covered up part of the borders on the menu, screenshot:
www.prntscr.com/28qwvv

If I'm being an idiot and my question is stupid please feel free to point it out as long as you give me a reason

Comment: Nothing stands out at first glance, but you should get rid of the table elements and create a jsfiddle.net.  Start simple also; get rid of all the positioning, widths, etc.  Get it functioning, and then add in those styles.  This is one of the first results in google for css menu, it would be a good starting point: http://csswizardry.com/2011/02/creating-a-pure-css-dropdown-menu/.  Also, your question isn't stupid, it's actually well done, especially for your first.

Comment: +1 @ChrisRockwell for recommending to move away from tables. Another thing comes to mind, what is the reasoning for running duplicate jQuery as well as the this var if nothing is physically being passed. A single $('ul').stop(true, true).slideToggle(100); should suffice.

Comment: Thanks guys, you've really helped me to clean up my code :) @ChrisRockwell If I moved away from tables how would i organise the menu? and the purpose of the jsfiddle would be to demonstrate what I've built? Yeah it was functioning thats why i added in the styles, then it didnt work when i moved it over although now thanks to the answer given i can see how stupid my mistake was :) Once again thanks for all the help

Comment: Use un ordered lists. see http://kyleschaeffer.com/development/navigation-using-unordered-lists/ && http://www.darkstardesign.com/darkstar-blog/2012/11/27/stretching-horizontal-navigation-menus-to-the-full-width-of-a-layout/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I noticed that you are applying an inline style position relative to your home TD.. Remove the inline style and add this to your css.

```
.menu_item {
   position: relative;
}
```

This should do the trick. Relative elements will contain absolute elements, and it appears that you are not containing it to the plugin width. See my comments above.

Comment: Thanks, i didnt spot that :) thought it would be a stupid mistake XD